# How to uninstall lsp servers

Tags: lsp

How do you uninstall lsp servers. I see the functions to update and install, but none to remove or uninstall.

I am using spacemacs, but an answer for vanilla emacs still helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was spacemacs was calling the package `mspyls` and `list-packages` has it under `lsp-python-ms`.

To uninstall do `M-x list-packages RET`, search for the package, hit `d` with your cursor on the package, then `x` to execute deletion.

Comment: IOW, the question should be "How to uninstall packages". It has nothing to do with lsp specifically. Correct?

Comment: What does IOW stand for? Search is not pulling anything relevant. Now that I see what was going on yes, this became an issue with uninstalling normal packages, but in the beginning, since I didn't find any `mspyls` packages, I thought something else was going on in the background, or it was stored in a specific directory, which warranted this question.

Comment: IOW = "In other words". I'm not saying you did anything wrong: I'm just confirming my understanding.

Comment: Absolutely! It's a good point to make!

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall a lsp server in Spacemacs delete the folder that has a similar name from     `~/.emacs.d/.cache/lsp/`

The folder name may have a different name because the folder name is the full name of the lsp-server.

If it is not there, try looking at sub-directories in that folder. After deleting restart emacs.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.  Specifically, I was getting `Warning (emacs): The javascript-typescript-langserver (jsts-ls) is unmaintained; it is recommended to use ts-ls or deno-ls instead.`, and there's no emacs package that corresponds to jsts-ls.  I had to delete `~/.emacs.d/.cache/lsp/npm/javascript-typescript-langserver` to make the obsolete lang server go away.

Comment: Oddly, this doesn't seem to work anymore, lsp information must be store somewhere other than just `.cache` now. After deleting this folder and restarting emacs, the language server backend I'm trying to remove, persists.